# Rspec: testing looping arrays , input = [] , output =[] for custom classes. ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, rspec

I'm trying to speed up my tests development using the examples I use to develop the function in the output.

I have two arrays: Input and output.

`function(input[0]) == output[0]`.

The loop is working, but it gets stuck in the last index. example: if input.length = 10 it always do function(input[10]) == output[10].

```
describe "multiple_chords" do
  input = ["A7 DMaj79", "E-7 A7", "D-7 G7", "Bb-7b5 Eb7b9" , "Bb-7b5 Eb7", "G7 A7", "D-7b5 G7b9", "D-79 G#7913"]
  output = [[{"root"=>"A", "def"=>"7"}, {"root"=>"D", "def"=>"Maj7"}], [{"root"=>"E", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"A", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"D", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"G", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"Bb", "def"=>"-7b5"}, {"root"=>"Eb", "tensions"=>"b9", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"Bb", "def"=>"-7b5"}, {"root"=>"Eb", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"G", "def"=>"7"}, {"root"=>"A", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"D", "def"=>"-7b5"}, {"root"=>"G", "tensions"=>"b9", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"D", "tensions"=>"9", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>["9", "13"], "def"=>"7"}]]

  for i in 0..input.length-1
    it "analyzes correctly #{input[i]}" do
      expect(IpmChords::multiple_chords(input[i])).to eq(output[i])
    end
  end
end
```

The output in the console is:

```
 6) IpmChords multiple_chords analyzes correctly Bb-7b5 Eb7
 Failure/Error: expect(IpmChords::multiple_chords(input[i])).to eq(output[i])

   expected: [{"root"=>"D", "tensions"=>"9", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>["9", "13"], "def"=>"7"}]
        got: [{"root"=>"D", "tensions"=>"9", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>"13", "def"=>""}]

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
    [{"root"=>"D", "tensions"=>"9", "def"=>"-7"},
   - {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>["9", "13"], "def"=>"7"}]
   + {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>"13", "def"=>""}]

 # ./spec/ipm_classes/ipm_chords_ipm_class_spec.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

7) IpmChords multiple_chords analyzes correctly E-7 A7
 Failure/Error: expect(IpmChords::multiple_chords(input[i])).to eq(output[i])

   expected: [{"root"=>"D", "tensions"=>"9", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>["9", "13"], "def"=>"7"}]
        got: [{"root"=>"D", "tensions"=>"9", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>"13", "def"=>""}]

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
    [{"root"=>"D", "tensions"=>"9", "def"=>"-7"},
   - {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>["9", "13"], "def"=>"7"}]
   + {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>"13", "def"=>""}]
```

You can see it is always evaluating the same array index, but the test name is changing for each loop iteration:

```
6) IpmChords multiple_chords analyzes correctly Bb-7b5 Eb7
7) IpmChords multiple_chords analyzes correctly E-7 A7
```

I think it will be a great time saver, and it should work, no??
Hope you can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You're running into a bit of a problem with Ruby's block bindings here. What's happening is that each block is going to bind to `i`, which remains in scope, which means that they're invoked, they're all going to use whatever `i` ends up being (which will be the last array index).

If you instead use Ruby's block iterators, it'll work:

```
describe "multiple_chords" do
  input = ["A7 DMaj79", "E-7 A7", "D-7 G7", "Bb-7b5 Eb7b9" , "Bb-7b5 Eb7", "G7 A7", "D-7b5 G7b9", "D-79 G#7913"]
  output = [[{"root"=>"A", "def"=>"7"}, {"root"=>"D", "def"=>"Maj7"}], [{"root"=>"E", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"A", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"D", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"G", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"Bb", "def"=>"-7b5"}, {"root"=>"Eb", "tensions"=>"b9", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"Bb", "def"=>"-7b5"}, {"root"=>"Eb", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"G", "def"=>"7"}, {"root"=>"A", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"D", "def"=>"-7b5"}, {"root"=>"G", "tensions"=>"b9", "def"=>"7"}], [{"root"=>"D", "tensions"=>"9", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"G#", "tensions"=>["9", "13"], "def"=>"7"}]]

  input.each_with_index do |chord, index|
    it "analyzes correctly #{chord}" do
      expect(IpmChords::multiple_chords(chord)).to eq(output[index])
    end
  end
end
```

The reason this works is that you don't end up creating a variable outside of each block that remains in scope, so each block ends up being invoked with the correct values. The values yielded to each loop are local to that loop, so you don't get "bleed over".

As an aside, idiomatic Ruby generally expects the use of enumerators rather than for loops.

A note on style; you can clean this up a bit by just defining and then iterating over a hash of expected inputs and outputs:

```
describe "multiple_chords" do
  CHORD_MAP = {
    "A7 DMaj79" => [{"root"=>"A", "def"=>"7"}, {"root"=>"D", "def"=>"Maj7"}],
    "E-7 A7"    => [{"root"=>"E", "def"=>"-7"}, {"root"=>"A", "def"=>"7"}],
    # ...
  }

  CHORD_MAP.each do |chord, result|
    it "analyzes correctly #{chord}" do
      expect(IpmChords::multiple_chords(chord)).to eq(result)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Chris' answer is a good and deserves recognition. I've adapted this approach for the general case of making my rspec tests data-driven.